# Not able to set state using this.setState in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using the geolocation API of js to get coordinate.
The long and lat values are getting set. I checked through console.log but the state variable longitude and latitude are not getting set despite calling the setState.

```
import React from 'react';

class Weather extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            longitude : '',
            latitude : ''
        }
    }
    
    componentDidMount(){
        var long = 'a';
        var lat = 'b';
        var a = function(pos){
            long = pos.coords.longitude
            lat = pos.coords.latitude
        }
        
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(a);
        this.setState({
            longitude: long,
            latitude: lat
        })
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="city">
                    <h1>City Name</h1>
                        <h3>lon:{this.state.longitude}</h3>
                        <h3>{this.state.latitude}</h3>
                </div>
                <div className="icon">
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default Weather
```

Comment: Well, you don't show the console log in your code, which is absolutely the key, position. setState is async, it might not be ready when you're trying to log it

Comment: `getCurrentPosition()` is **asynchronous** . Just like you can't eat a pizza before it gets delivered, you can't access data that hasn't been received yet

Comment: State variables are updated in the next render cycle of React components.  Check [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html). You might be using console log within the method ```componentDidMount()```, which doesn't show updated values right after they are set. Add a console log inside ```componentDidUpdate()``` method and you will see the updated state variable values.

Comment: what so you suggest i should do to set the longitude and latitude?

Comment: @dhruvtailor, after everything the most probable way would be to make your `componentDidMount` async and then await for the geolocation.

Answer (score 0):

Since `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` is asynchronous, you could use `async/await` functionality like this:

Declare your method where you get the current position, `await` for the result anf then set your state.

```
getPosition = async () => {

  let promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve, reject);
  });

  let pos = await promise;

  this.setState({
    longitude: pos.coords.longitude,
    latitude: pos.coords.latitude
  })
}
```

and then in `componentDidMount` call this method

```
componentDidMount(){
  this.getPosition();
}
```

Comment: hmm did you try the second variation? include the `setState` inside the function? does this still not work?

Comment: @Apostolos, in the `componentDidMount` I guess the `getPosition()` is again asynchronous and this still isn't resolved.

Comment: sorry yes correct, we need to handle differently the function declaration. check updated answer

Comment: @dhruvtailor try my updated answer and it should work.

Comment: actually you cannot declare a variable outside methods in react. It gives error.

Comment: I worked it out using your previous approach @Apostolos.                                      
     async function getPosition(t) {
            let promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
              navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve, reject);
            });
            let pos = await promise;

            t.setState({
              longitude: pos.coords.longitude,
              latitude: pos.coords.latitude
            })
          }
          getPosition(this)                  Just had to pass 'this'. Thanks

Comment: @dhruvtailor yes you are correct. Sorry I have been using hooks most of the time so I'm used to this type of programming now :) I have re-updated the answer to meet the `React.Component` style of coding.

Answer (score 0):

After everything, you have already tried, go and make your `componentDidMount()` an `async` function.

```js
import React from 'react';

class Weather extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            longitude : '',
            latitude : ''
        }
    }
    
    async componentDidMount(){
        var long = 'a';
        var lat = 'b';
        var a = function(pos){
            long = pos.coords.longitude
            lat = pos.coords.latitude
        }
        
        await navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(a);
        this.setState({
             longitude: long,
             latitude: lat
        })
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="city">
                    <h1>City Name</h1>
                        <h3>lon:{this.state.longitude}</h3>
                        <h3>{this.state.latitude}</h3>
                </div>
                <div className="icon">
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default Weather
```

Comment: as i mentioned above this approach gives error at this.setState

Comment: @dhruvtailor , I see the call back is not an anonymous function like in most cases, I encounter, so I just edited, what must work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I just worked it out using some modification in @Apostolos answer.

```
componentDidMount(){
        var long = 'a';
        var lat = 'b';
        
        async function getPosition(t) {
            let promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
              navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve, reject);
            });
            let pos = await promise;

            t.setState({
              longitude: pos.coords.longitude,
              latitude: pos.coords.latitude
            })
          }
          getPosition(this)
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to convert the `getCurrentPosition` into a promise if you are not going to chain it any further. The cleanest solution in my opinion would be to just use the callback function here.

The important difference with what you already do inside the question is that I move the `this.setState` call inside the `getCurrentPosition` callback.

Note that you must use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to keep the `this` value for the `getCurrentPosition` callback the same as inside the `componentDidMount` function.

```
componentDidMount() {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    ({coords: {longitude, latitude}}) => this.setState({longitude, latitude})
  );
}
```

For more info about the `{coords: {longitude, latitude}}` syntax, I'd like to redirect you to the [MDN Destructing assignment - Object destructing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) page.